# How to add widgets to a label in scrollview Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to make a chat page which looks like a standard messaging app on a phone (Whatsapp, Imessage etc). To do this I have created a screen which contains ScrollView and have added a label widget to it.

To get the desired effect of the Whatsapp/Imessage look I think I then want a label widget to be added to the label on the ScrollView everytime the send button is pressed, this will then add the text of the text input box onto the screen.

Is it possible to add a label to another label? Every question I've looked at so far has been about adding a widget to a BoxLayout or GridLayout.

I'm also not sure on how I'll get the position of the label to change everytime the button is pressed but one step at a time!

kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    ChatPage:

<ChatPage>:
    name: "chat_page"
    layout_content: layout_content

    NavigationLayout:
        id: nav_layout
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                text: "Test"

        FloatLayout:
            MDToolbar:
                pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                md_bg_color: 0.2, 0.6, 1, 1

            ScrollView:
                size_hint: 1, 0.6
                pos_hint: {"top" : 0.8, "bottom" : 0.5}
                GridLayout:
                    id: layout_content
                    cols: 1
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos

                    Label:
                        text_size: self.width - 20, None
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.texture_size[1]
                        color: 0,0,0,1

            BoxLayout:
                TextInput:
                    id: msg
                    hint_text: "Type your message here"
                    pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 0.15}
                    size_hint: 0.75, 0.15
                Button:
                    text: "Send"
                    background_normal: ""
                    background_color: 0, 0.6, 0, 1
                    pos_hint: {"x": 0.75, "top": 0.15}
                    size_hint: 0.25, 0.15
                    on_release: root.btn_press()

<SmoothLabel@Label>:
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    background_normal: ""
    back_color: 1,0,1,1
    border_radius: [6]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.2,0.6,1,1 #This changes the label colour
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: self.border_radius
```

py file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)

class SmoothLabel(Label):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ChatPage(Screen):
    layout_content = ObjectProperty(None)
    def btn_press(self):
        if self.ids.msg.text:
            self.layout_content.add_widget(SmoothLabel(text=self.ids.msg.text, size_hint_x=0.5, size_hint_y=0.1, pos_hint={"x": 0.1, "top": 0.8}, background_color=(0.2, 0.6, 1, 1)))
            self.ids.msg.text = ""
        else:
            pass

class MyApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
        sm = WindowManager()

        screens = [ChatPage(name="chat_page")]
        for screen in screens:
            sm.add_widget(screen)

        sm.current = "chat_page"
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Thanks

Comment: A better approach would be to use a vertical `BoxLayout` in your `ScrollView`, and just add `Labels` to that. Or just add more text to the one `Label'.

Comment: Generally, you only add `Widgets` to containers (like `Layouts`) that are designed to contain (and layout) contained `Widgets`. The `Label` `Widget` is not designed to  layout children `Widgets`.

Comment: OK I've edited the code to include a ```GridLayout``` (the scrolling wasn't working with a ```BoxLayout```, not sure what I was doing wrong?). I've also added in the code in the py file in the ```ChatPage``` class. I've added an ```id``` to my ```GridLayout``` and am then trying to refer to it in my py file as ```self.layout_content``` to add the ```SmoothLabel``` widget to but when I run the code no label gets added, there's no error. just nothing happening?

Comment: I can't actually run your code (I get many error messages, perhaps my kivymd version v0.103.0 is incompatible). I would suggest adding print statements in your `btn_press` method to see what is actually happening. Or better yet, if you are using PyCharm,  run you code in debug mode with a breakpoint in the `btn_press` method.

Comment: You can delete the kivymd code, all that I'm using it for in this section is the toolbar at the top of the page. I ran the debugger and it doesn't show anything happening at this section of code ```self.layout_content.add_widget(SmoothLabel())```, it just skips over it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a few changes to your code (in addition to removing all the `kivyMD`) to get it to work:

First, I changed the `SmoothLabel` rule in your `kv` to:

```
<SmoothLabel>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: self.texture_size
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    background_normal: ""
    back_color: 1,0,1,1
    border_radius: [6]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.2,0.6,1,1 #This changes the label colour
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: self.border_radius
```

Took out the `@Label` since that is already specified in your python code, and added the `size_hint` and `size` (otherwise, the `GridLayout` decides the size of the `SmoothLabel` children).

Also, removed the

```
background_color=(0.2, 0.6, 1, 1)
```

from the `SmoothLabel` creation (that was throwing an exception for me), so the `ChatPage` definition now looks like:

```
class ChatPage(Screen):
    layout_content = ObjectProperty(None)
    def btn_press(self):
        if self.ids.msg.text:
            self.layout_content.add_widget(SmoothLabel(text=self.ids.msg.text))
            self.ids.msg.text = ""
        else:
            pass
```

The `Label` widget has no `background_color` attribute. And, since I added `size_hint` to the rule, I removed it from the `SmoothLabel()` call. Also, the `GridLayout` does not support `pos_hint`.

That was enough to get the code working for me.

Comment: Do you think to get the desired effect of the messages (WhatsApp/Imessage style) I would be better off using a ```FloatLayout``` instead of ```GridLayout```. Then I'd be able to control the position of the ```Widgets``` better on the screen? Or could this be achieved with a ```GridLayout```?

Comment: Not sure what effect you mean, but `FloatLayout` gives you more control, and it also burdens you with more responsibility (you MUST position the `Labels` and adjust the size of the `FloatLayout`). The `BoxLayout` provides you with a `minimum_height` calculation, and allows you to position the `Labels` left to right within each row.

Comment: I mean whereby the messages appear in labels either side of the screen, and in different colours dependant on whether you've sent the message or received the message. All the examples of kivy chat applications I've seen have had quite an uninspiring old-school style to them. Maybe I could achieve the desired effect with a ```BoxLayout```, if a message is sent then a ```Label``` appears on the right hand side of the ```BoxLayout``` and if it has been sent by the other user then it appears on the left hand side of the ```BoxLayout```

Comment: Yes, you can do that easily with a `BoxLayout`.